# Improve speed of ng-repeat having ng-include inside

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat with a div inside it having ng-include on an array of json to differentiate scope of same template included but this approach is slowing down loading of page when size of array increases. Can anyone suggest a way to increase speed of rendering or an alternate approach to this? My approach is exemplified in fiddle.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/toBeIncluded.html">
    This is a partial with something unique:
    <input ng-model="partialVar.val" />
</script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="partialVar in partialStuff">
        <div ng-include src="'/toBeIncluded.html'">    
        </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="getValues()">Values</button>
    <div>{{fvalues}}</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle showing my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/CES78/)

Comment: Use $timeout. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **$timeout** to improve speed.

Make your array inside **$timeout** so that it will update view by including templates in chunks. Though it will take as much time as currently it takes but it will not hands up your browser. See below approach.

**CODE**

```
var partialStuff = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"];
$scope.partialStuff = [];

for(var i=0;i<partialStuff.length;i++)
{
    (function(index) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.partialStuff.push(partialStuff[index]);
        },20);
    })(i);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure time is fixed for digest cycle to run and rendering dom for any size of template included?

Comment: It can be vary but I think it will not cause any problem here.

Comment: You could also replace ng-include by a very simple directive using '/toBeIncluded.html' as templateUrl.